# How to make an xml file (just the xml file) available at a specific url?

Tags: xml

I'm trying to include an xml file in my WP site where you could go to a url, much like this one:

**www.example.com/somepage/anotherpage/thefile.xml**

and view "thefile.xml" - no header, no footer, just the xml file.

I've been searching for ways to accomplish this for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

simply add as a link wherever you want.

```
<a href="www.example.com/somepage/anotherpage/thefile.xml">www.example.com/somepage/anotherpage/thefile.xml<a>
```

I have done the same [here](http://poeticcoding.com/main/wordpress/wordpress-a-simple-xml-sitemap-generator/)